# How can I capture data which will be sent to stdout in c++?

Tags: c++, stream, stdout

how can I capture data which will be sent to the stdout in c++?

I found here:

```
   // This can be an ofstream as well or any other ostream
   std::stringstream buffer;

   // Save cout's buffer here
   std::streambuf *sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();

   // Redirect cout to our stringstream buffer or any other ostream
   std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf());

   std::cout << "Hello!";

   // When done redirect cout to its old self
   std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);

   std::cout << "STD data: \n";
   std::cout << buffer.get();
```

And this doesn't work. 'Hello' still outputs before 'STD data:', and `buffer.get()` returns '-1'. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write:

```
  std::cout << buffer.str(); //not buffer.get();
```

Now its working : http://ideone.com/W8mW8

---

By the way, `std::stringstream::get()` returns `std::istream`. See this :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/

Recall that `std::stringstream` derives from `std::istream`. So don't get confused. :-)